# IP protected Enclosure and Conformal Coating

Tags: waterproof, conformal-coating

I have an aluminium Enclosure and I am trying to make it waterproof by using Silicone.

1. Is there any corrosion testing I can perform to Check Corrosion of
   Silicone or aluminium: to check the integrity of my Ingress protection over some time?
2. Just to be on safe side can double protection
   through Conformal Coating make sense?

Comment: If it is totally sealed, you may have condensation issues, so you might want to add that to the list.

Comment: cant I handle this while enclosing the PCB in controlled Environment, such that humidity inside my casing is very low?

Comment: My understanding is that when it temperature cycles, it will probably 'breathe' a little.

Comment: I read in many places that silicone joint is air tight. So is there any way silicone can also "breathe"

Comment: Sorry I was wrong,SR is not water VAPOR proof.

Comment: Silicon is permeable, so air will eventually permeate through.

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of silicone adhesive, if worried about corrosion they should avoid acetoxy (smells of vinegar) or oxime (gives off MEKO which corrodes copper and brass).  They should use an alkoxy grade (gives off alcohol) or a one part addition cure - no by-products of cure - cures anaerobically, but will require heat to cure and adhere on just aluminium this would be the optimum choice.